# Mobile Broadband API: "Pin is required" exception but pin is set

Tags: c#, com, mobile-broadband-api

I'm trying to get up & running with the [Mobile Broadband API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm using it from C#, using the instructions found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487392.aspx).

I have a problem with it though: when the modem device is locked (i.e., PIN is required), I want to set the pin programmatically and the continue to make a connection, but the latter fails with "Pin is required", even though I just correctly set the PIN.

The Mobile Broadband API offers the `IMbnPin` interface to set the pin, but this is an asynchronous operation, so you have to register for the `OnEnterComplete` event (part of the `IMbnPinEvents` interface) which signals that the operation has completed. I assumed this should be enough, but apparently it isn't.

The class below is a minimal, self-contained sample that demonstrates the problem. You can use it in a console application like this:

```
var testInstance = new MbnTest();
testInstance.Test("XXXX"); // replace with actual PIN code
```

(You will also need an Interop dll to compile it, which you can find [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/80446/Interop.MbnApi.dll))

The test class contains a ManualResetEvent field to coordinate between the Enter and OnEnterComplete methods.

In the Test method, I subscribe to the IMbnPinEvents, instantiate the IMbnPin, call the (asynchronous) `Enter` method and call `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne` to block the current thread. In OnEnterComplete, I can verify that the pin was correctly set and then signal the `ManualResetEvent` so the Test method continues execution. If I continue immediately after that with the `TryToGetConnectionState()` call, I get an exception E_MBN_PIN_REQUIRED (0x80548210). If I wait 'long enough' using Console.ReadLine(), everything works fine. So it looks like I need to wait for another event, but I can't find which one.

Any ideas? What am I missing?

```
// warning: this is sample code, needs to be better structured for production use
class MbnTest : IMbnPinEvents
{
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _resetEventPin = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public void Test(string pinCode)
    {
        var interfacemanager = (IMbnInterfaceManager)new MbnInterfaceManager();

        SubscribeToPinEvents(interfacemanager);

        var mbnPin = GetPin(interfacemanager);

        uint requestId;
        Trace.WriteLine("Setting PIN");
        mbnPin.Enter(pinCode, out requestId);
        Trace.WriteLine("Waiting for OnEnterComplete");

        // wait for the OnEnterComplete event
        _resetEventPin.WaitOne();

        Trace.WriteLine("press enter to retrieve connection state");
        Console.ReadLine();

        TryToGetConnectionState();
    }

    void IMbnPinEvents.OnEnterComplete(IMbnPin pin, ref MBN_PIN_INFO pinInfo, uint requestID, int status)
    {
        // reports MBN_PIN_STATE_NONE which means no pin is required
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("OnEnterComplete: pin state = {0}", pinInfo.pinState));
        // signal the ManualResetEvent to unblock the thread waiting for the Enter Pin operation to complete
        _resetEventPin.Set();
    }

    private void SubscribeToPinEvents(IMbnInterfaceManager interfacemanager)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Subscribing to IMbnPinEvents");
        var guidPinEvents = typeof (IMbnPinEvents).GUID;
        var connectionPointContainer = (IConnectionPointContainer) interfacemanager;
        IConnectionPoint connectionPoint;
        connectionPointContainer.FindConnectionPoint(ref guidPinEvents, out connectionPoint);
        uint cookie;
        connectionPoint.Advise(this, out cookie);
    }

    private static IMbnPin GetPin(IMbnInterfaceManager interfacemanager)
    {
        IMbnInterface mbnInterface = interfacemanager.GetInterfaces().OfType<IMbnInterface>().First();
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("mbnInterface: {0}", mbnInterface.GetReadyState()));

        var pinMgr = (IMbnPinManager)mbnInterface;
        var mbnPin = pinMgr.GetPin(MBN_PIN_TYPE.MBN_PIN_TYPE_PIN1);
        return mbnPin;
    }

    private static void TryToGetConnectionState()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Retrieving mbn connection");
        var connectionManager = (IMbnConnectionManager)new MbnConnectionManager();
        var mbnConnection = connectionManager.GetConnections().OfType<IMbnConnection>().First();
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("connection: {0}", mbnConnection.ConnectionID));
        MBN_ACTIVATION_STATE state;
        string profilename;
        mbnConnection.GetConnectionState(out state, out profilename);
    }


    void IMbnPinEvents.OnChangeComplete(IMbnPin pin, ref MBN_PIN_INFO pinInfo, uint requestID, int status)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IMbnPinEvents.OnEnableComplete(IMbnPin pin, ref MBN_PIN_INFO pinInfo, uint requestID, int status)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    void IMbnPinEvents.OnDisableComplete(IMbnPin pin, ref MBN_PIN_INFO pinInfo, uint requestID, int status)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    void IMbnPinEvents.OnUnblockComplete(IMbnPin pin, ref MBN_PIN_INFO pinInfo, uint requestID, int status)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: I needed to wait for the network registration to become active before making the connection. Kind of obvious in hindsight. To make it work, I made the following changes:

- before setting the pin, subscribe to the `IMbnRegistrationEvents` interface
- in the `IMbnRegistrationEvents.OnRegisterStateChange` method, check whether the
  registration state is 'registered' (i.e., one of the values MBN_REGISTER_STATE_HOME,
  MBN_REGISTER_STATE_ROAMING or MBN_REGISTER_STATE_PARTNER).

From then on, you can use the `IMbnConnection.Connect` method to create a broadband connection.

Kinda hard to find documentation on this... There is the [Mobile Broadband Connection Manager Development Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg454524) on msdn, but I couldn't find any specifics in there. Also, I'm not sure if there is anything provider- or device-specific in this behaviour.

Comment: I had the same problem and couldn't find an explanation for it. However, the problem only occurred on Windows 7 with a temporary connection profile (`MBN_CONNECTION_MODE.MBN_CONNECTION_MODE_TMP_PROFILE`). On a Windows 10, on the other hand, I had no problem using a temporary connection profile. Both machines are of the same type.